# Python 3 If statement not returning what's supposed to

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, input

I've recently started learning python and was experimenting with if statements and user inputs. My code was working fine, but now it's not (I may have changed something by accident, but I have no clue as to what it can be). No matter what I input, the console always returns the first if statement - the hours to seconds conversion. What's causing this?

```
print('Welcome to the time to seconds converter')
option = input('Please choose what you want to convert ')

if option == 'hours' or 'Hours':
    hours = int(input('How many hours to seconds would you like to convert? '))
    product1 = (hours * 60) * 60
    print(hours, 'hours are', product1, 'seconds')

elif option == 'minutes' or 'Minutes':
    minutes = int(input('Please choose how many minutes to seconds you would like to convert '))
    product2 = minutes * 60
    print(minutes, 'minutes are', product2, 'seconds')

elif option == 'days' or 'Days':
    days = int(input('How many days would you like to convert to seconds? '))
    product3 = ((days * 24) * 60) * 60
    print(product3)

elif option == 'years' or 'Years':
    years = int(input('How many years would you like to convert in to seconds? '))
    product4 = (((years * 365) * 24) * 60) * 60
    print(product4)

else:
    print('Sorry, I do not recognize that')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your checks need to be modified slightly:

```
if option == 'hours' or 'Hours':
```

should be written:

```
if option == 'hours' or option == 'Hours':
```

## What is happening behind the scenes:

You mention that your code always returns the results of the first if statement. The reason that this is happening is based on two characteristics of Python:

- How Python processes the `if` statement
- How Python handles truth testing in strings with content vs empty strings

Let's look at both:

## How Python processes the if statement

Python considers the if statement as two separate checks, which I will segment using parentheses for clarity:

```
if (option == 'hours') or ('Hours'):
```

In this case, depending on what you type in, option may OR may not be 'hours'. if it is not 'hours', then that test will return `False` and Python will move on to perform the second check which is equivalent to

```
if ('Hours'):
```

The check if 'Hours' always returns True. Which may seem odd, until we consider how Python handles strings with and without content.

## How Python handles truth testing in strings with content vs empty strings

When Python tests to see if an item is True (truthy) OR False (falsy), it uses some common conventions:

- Empty containers or strings are generally considered to be False
  (i.e. `''`)
- Containers or strings that have some form of content are
  considered to be True (i.e. `'hello'`, `'a'`, `'Hours'`)

So a test of

```
if 'Hours':             # returns True
```

will always return True, but a test of

```
if '':                  # an empty string, returns False
```

will always return False

The revised version of the code that is suggested at the top is equivalent to:

```
if (option == 'hours') or (option == 'Hours'):
```

and creates two separate tests of `options` versus the text.

## Alternate ways to do this same thing:

There are several ways to handle your tests in a manner that might be more Pythonic:

```
if options.lower() == 'hours':
```

Which takes the inputs and makes a lowercase copy of the input to test against a single value. The advantage to this is that it covers all the bases, i.e. if the user types in HOURS, Hours, houRs, HOurs, etc)

```
if options in ['hours', 'Hours']:
```

This checks to see if options is in a set collection of allowable answers. The benefit of this is it allows you to add new options later in a simple and easy to manage way. i.e.

```
if options in ['hours', 'Hours', 'HOURS']:
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `lower()` so that you can ignore the case of the input entirely.

```
print('Welcome to the time to seconds converter')
option = input('Please choose what you want to convert ').lower()

if option == 'hours':
    ...

elif option == 'minutes':
    ...

elif option == 'days':
    ...

elif option == 'years':
    ...

else:
    print('Sorry, I do not recognize that')
```

Answer (score 0):

And you can make it simpler by using.lower() it will covert string in lower caps no matter how you writted

If option.lower()== ‘hours’